# my Nginx is working fine but nginx.service is showing error ;; nginx.service: Unit entered failed state ;; nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'

Tags: nginx

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
└─override.conf

Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-08-15 14:47:52 UTC; 26min ago

Process: 31083 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=2)
Process: 31096 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 31092 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 31087 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 31095 (nginx)
Tasks: 2
Memory: 6.9M
CPU: 3.635s
CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
├─31095 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
└─31098 nginx: worker process

Aug 15 14:47:52 ip-* * * * systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.

Aug 15 14:47:52 ip- * * * * systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

Comment: What lead to this output? What is your question?

Comment: everything was running normal suddenly one day my app was showing 502 timeout error. so i added proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600; these lines to /etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf. and i have pid problem so i  did mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf, systemctl daemon-reload, systemctl restart nginx ,systemctl status nginx. this one to nginx from that time these errors came.

Comment: Q. how to remove these errors from nginx? can you please help.